# Build a list with JSON and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, list

I need to build a list using the parameters "name" taken from my file "sendjson.php" (in json, of course). How can i create a list using jQuery like this one?

```
<div id="firstresultname">Firstresultname</div>
<div id="secondresultname">Secondresultname</div>
```

I don't know how much result will be so is possible to detect and write the right number on div? Thanks!

Comment: please define "list". please show sendjson.php.

Comment: can you tell where you are having the problem? specify the json response you are getting and how you want to get it displayed...

Comment: For list i mean a series of elements ... this is an example of the result fom sendjson.php: {"items":[{"name":"iPod Shuffle"},{"name":"Nintendo Wi"}]}  - i need to show one result for each div. using the example i posted in json, it should become <div>iPod shuffle</div> <div>Nintendo Wii</div>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$.each(json, function(key, value){
    $("body").append('<div id="'+value+'">'+value+'</div>');
});
```

or  just

```
$.each(json, function(key, value){
    $("body").append('<div>'+value+'</div>');
});
```

to retreive json & proccess, do following

```
$.ajax({
    'url' : 'yoururl.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json){
        $.each(json, function(key, value){
            $("body").append('<div>'+value+'</div>');
        });
    }
});
```